# How to find the row index of a particular value from a table?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I want to return the row header value for a particular value.

```
A 1 2 3 
B 4 5 6
C 7 8 9
```

For example, if the value is 5 it should return B.

here the digits and alphabet represent Date data type.

I tried

```
=INDEX(A1:A3,MATCH(C3,B1:D3,0),1)
```

but it can't be applied in the case of multiple columns.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you just have a single value that would equal your search-value:

```
=INDEX(A1:A3,SUMPRODUCT((B1:D3=5)*(ROW(B1:D3))))
```

If you have Microsoft365, you could try:

```
=CONCAT(IF(B1:D3=5,A1:A3,""))
```

Comment: Will this work if the values and row headers are date type?

Answer (score 2):

Can try-

```
=INDEX(A1:A3,MAX(ROW(A1:A3)*(B1:D3=F1)))
```

[image]

Comment: Will this work if the values and row headers are date type?

Comment: @TIMER Yes. It will also work for date type values. On excel dates are nothing but numbers.

Comment: Thanks, @Harun24HR for the help. For me, it is working in the case of numbers but not when the values are date.

Comment: Can you show data sample with date? Are they actual dates (properly formatted as date) or dates are stored as text?